# Is the limit of cauchy sequences is cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Suppose we have a family $(x^n_k)\subset X$ such that $x^n_k \rightarrow x_k$ in $X$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ for any $k.$ Also suppose that $(x^n_k)$ is Cauchy in $k$ for any $n.$ The metric $d$ is continuous, so we have $d(x_k,x_l)=\lim_n d(x^n_k,x^n_l).$ This means that for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $|d(x_k,x_l)|\leq \epsilon + |d(x^n_k,x^n_l)|$ whenever $n \geq N$ so as $k,l \rightarrow \infty $ $d(x_k,x_l)\rightarrow 0.$ I feel like something is wrong, I will appreciate if someone can point out my mistake.

Comment: Look at $x^n_k = k$ for $k< n$, and $0$ for $k \geqslant n$. What can you say about $(x^n_k)$ and where does your proof fails to apply here?